Android Firebase Logging In Issue
I am having trouble logging in to my Android application with Firebase. Every time I login with the right credentials it gives me this error in the logcat:
2024-04-24 19:00:45.171 29824-29824 RecaptchaCallWrapper    com.example.homework3                E  Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
2024-04-24 19:00:45.171 29824-29824 LoginException          com.example.homework3                E  Login failed: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
If anyone can help me get it to work properly I would greatly appreciate it, below are the relevant codes I have:
(sorry for all the code I am really want to use Firebase for future project so I just want to know what I am doing wrong
//LoginScreen.kt

package com.example.homework3

import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.PasswordVisualTransformation
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

@Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: LoginScreenViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    val initialEmail = currentUser?.email ?: ""
    var email by remember { mutableStateOf(initialEmail) }
    var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 15.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
            shadowElevation = 8.dp
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 15.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Login",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.copy(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                )
                TextField(
                    value = email,
                    onValueChange = { email = it },
                    label = { Text("Email") }
                )
                TextField(
                    value = password,
                    onValueChange = { password = it },
                    label = { Text("Password") },
                    visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
                )
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.loginFirebase(email, password, {
                            navController.navigate("salesList")  // Assuming "salesList" is your destination on successful login
                        }, {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Login unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        })
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Log In")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class LoginScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    fun loginFirebase(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        successfulLoginHandler: () -> Unit,
        unsuccessfulLoginHandler: () -> Unit
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
                val email = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.email // Safely access email
                Log.d("LoginSuccess", "Logged in with email: $email")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    successfulLoginHandler()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("LoginException", "Login failed: ${e.message}")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    unsuccessfulLoginHandler()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//SalesRepository.kt

package com.example.homework3

import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

class SalesRepository(private val db: FirebaseFirestore) {

    suspend fun addSale(sale: Sale) {
        db.collection("Hwk4Sales").document().set(mapOf(
            "name" to sale.name,
            "amount" to sale.amount.toString()
        )).await()
    }

    fun getAllSales(): Flow<List<Sale>> = flow {
        val snapshot = db.collection("Hwk4Sales").get().await()
        val sales = snapshot.documents.map { doc ->
            Sale(
                name = doc.getString("name") ?: "NAME EMPTY",
                amount = doc.getString("amount")?.toDouble() ?: 0.0
            )
        }
        emit(sales)
    }
}

I tried to use these rules in Firebase which im sure it is right:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
}
}

and this was my Application.kt code before:
//Application.kt

package com.example.homework3

import android.app.Application
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp

class MyApp : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApp
        lateinit var salesRepo: SalesRepository
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

        // Check if Firebase has already been initialized
        if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) { 
        }

        salesRepo = SalesRepository()
    }

but the firebase is already initialized using my SHA1 key

That's a debug message (indicated by the D in there), not an error. What's the actual problem you're experiencing?

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted almost 250 lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Besides that, did you try to catch the exceptions that might be thrown if the read/write operations fail?

Sorry guys, I get this error logging in: 'Login failed: com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.' I think it has to do with my LoginScreen.kt and LoginScreenViewModel.kt code

@AlexMamo  I just edited my question sorry about that, the error I am encountering is telling me a network error but I do not know how if my wifi works and I have all the dependencies.

Which operation throws that error?

@AlexMamo Seems like the LoginScreenViewModel code because I put a LoginException which is " Log.e("LoginException", "Login failed: ${e.message}")" and get this error:  09:41:42.818  6963-6963  LoginException  E  Login failed: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
